# Calculate time diff by rows in group in SQL

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, window-functions

I have a dataset with user site visits and visit timestamp. How I can group my users by id and calculate the time difference between user visits in SQL? Sorry for noob question I'm a newbie in SQL trying to build few reports.

My dataset example:

```
+----------+------------+---------------------+
| userID   | visitID    | vsitTS              |
+----------+------------+---------------------+
| user01   | visit01    | 2019-05-13 01:00:00 |
| user01   | visit02    | 2019-05-13 01:10:00 |
| user02   | visit01    | 2019-05-13 01:05:00 |
| user02   | visit02    | 2019-05-13 01:10:00 |
| user02   | visit03    | 2019-05-13 01:20:00 |
| user02   | visit04    | 2019-05-13 01:30:00 |
+----------+------------+---------------------+
```

I need result something like this:

```
+----------+------------+---------------+
| userID   | visitID    | time_dif_sec  |
+----------+------------+---------------+
| user01   | visit01    | 0             |
| user01   | visit02    | 10            |
| user02   | visit01    | 0             |
| user02   | visit02    | 5             |
| user02   | visit03    | 10            |
| user02   | visit04    | 10            |
+----------+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  userID, 
  visitID, 
  IFNULL(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(visitTS, LAG(visitTS) OVER(win), SECOND), 0) AS time_diff_sec, 
  IFNULL(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(visitTS, LAG(visitTS) OVER(win), MINUTE), 0) AS time_diff_min 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY visitTS)
```

If to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'user01' userID, 'visit01' visitID, TIMESTAMP '2019-05-13 01:00:00' visitTS UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user01', 'visit02', '2019-05-13 01:10:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user02', 'visit01', '2019-05-13 01:05:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user02', 'visit02', '2019-05-13 01:10:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user02', 'visit03', '2019-05-13 01:20:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user02', 'visit04', '2019-05-13 01:30:00' 
)
SELECT 
  userID, 
  visitID, 
  IFNULL(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(visitTS, LAG(visitTS) OVER(win), SECOND), 0) AS time_diff_sec, 
  IFNULL(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(visitTS, LAG(visitTS) OVER(win), MINUTE), 0) AS time_diff_min 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY visitTS)
```

output is

```
Row userID  visitID time_diff_sec   time_diff_min    
1   user01  visit01 0               0    
2   user01  visit02 600             10   
3   user02  visit01 0               0    
4   user02  visit02 300             5    
5   user02  visit03 600             10   
6   user02  visit04 600             10
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks. One more question, how to count the chain of sessions (visits) for each user where time_diff <= 5 minutes? For user01 - is 0, for user02 - is 1 (visit01 and visit02)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `lag()`?. It gives you a previous row value.
For Bigquery you can use `UNIX_SECONDS()` to convert timestamp to seconds and for MySQL you can use `to_seconds()`.

```
  select userid, visitid, 
  (UNIX_SECONDS(visitTS) - UNIX_SECONDS (lag(visitTS) over (partition by 
  userid order by userid, visitid))) as time_dif_sec 
  from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function `lag()` to get the timestamp of the "previous" visit, and then date functions.

In MySQL (window functions are available in version 8.0 only):

```
select
    t.*,
    coalesce(
        to_seconds(visitTS)
        - to_seconds(lag(visiTS) over(partition by userID order by visitTS),
        0) ts_diff_seconds
from mytable t
```

In BigQuery, you can use `timestamp_to_sec()` instead of `to_seconds()`.